# GoogleCloudMessaging APIs Implementing GCM Client

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

hello i am following the official documentation of android to send the push notification as the old method is deprecated but im facing problem in implementing GCM Client

```
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html
```

the tutorial is written here, scroll down and see

```
private void registerInBackground()
```

when i write this function on my app it gives me this error

```
Syntax error on token "void", @ expected
```

i have googled it and i know the error now that this method is trying to create a method inside a method but still im confused because it is the official documentation i must have done something wrong, can anybody point out plz?
here is the method on this tutorial:

```
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                // is using accounts.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
    ...
    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
      // Your implementation here.
    }
}
```

now see that sendRegistrationIdToBackend is inside a method itself, any help plz?

Answer (score 11):

here is the solution i found for it and disappointed that 33 people viewed it but nobody bother to ans anyways here is the code

```
private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it
                    // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device will send
                    // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message using the
                    // 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```